# Is this a Functor

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, functor

Recently I am learning functors and monads but it seems a little bit confusing. I have written this to chain multiple operations and wonder if it is a functor and I understand it correctly?

```
function Init(store = {}) {
  const map = (fn) => {
    const result = fn(store)
    return Init(result ? {...store, ...result} : store)
  }
  const unwrap = () => store
  return {
    map,
    unwrap
  }
}

// example usage
Init()
.map(fetchData)
.map(fetchOtherData)
.map(compareTwoData)
.map(saveAllData)
// ...etc
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"functor"_? AFAIK there are different definitions and I've never heard this term in context of JavaScript. The tag `functor` contains multiple definitions. _"1. Function object. In object-oriented languages, it is a feature that allows objects to be used as if they were ordinary functions."_ This is true for all functions in JavaScript. Every function is an object.

Comment: @jabaa [Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor)

Comment: @VLAZ That's the mathematical context but I don't see the relation to the posted code.

Comment: @jabaa functional programming has a concept called "functor" which is closely related to the mathematical concept. And it's also what OP shows here.

Comment: @VLAZ You mean this link [Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming))

Comment: @jabaa actually yes. I didn't pay enough attention to the page I copied. You're right.

Comment: @jabaa it's the Haskell definition. And the tag is currently unfocused. It might need to be replaced with multiple. One tag should correspond to one topic, not group multiple disparate ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is, because Functors must preserve composition `map(g°h)=map(g)°map(h)`, which yours does not:

```js
function Init(store = {}) {
    const map = (fn) => {
        const result = fn(store)
        return Init(result ? {...store, ...result} : store)
    }
    const unwrap = () => store
    return {
        map,
        unwrap
    }
}

a = x => ({...x, a:1})
b = x => 0


console.log(Init({X:1}).map(a).map(b).unwrap())
console.log(Init({X:1}).map(x => b(a(x))).unwrap())
```

Here's an example of a basic Functor that satisfies both functor laws:

```js
function Functor(value) {
    const fmap = (fn) => {
        const result = fn(value)
        return Functor(result)
    }
    return {fmap, value}
}

//

let id = x => x
let a = x => x * 5
let b = x => x + 3


// identity
console.log(
    Functor(7).value === Functor(7).fmap(id).value
)

// composition
console.log(
    Functor(7).fmap(a).fmap(b).value ===
    Functor(7).fmap(x => b(a(x))).value
)
```

Comment: Thank you alot. So is that it? It looks a lot simpler than tutorials. Is fmap stands for flatmap? Also can you give simple Monad example?

Comment: `fmap` is a name for the generic Functor map, to differentiate it from the plain `map` which only works on lists.

Comment: @user8190223 georg's functor is only the identity functor, i.e. it provides just enough structure to be a functor but without doing something special. When you look at the id functor all you've learned is what a type needs to be formally a functor. But the real power of functors lies in the special semantics each functor encodes, except for the id functor.